# How to convert kafka message value to a particular schema?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am trying to read data from Kafka topics using Pyspark. I want to transform that data into a particular schema. But unable to do so.

Here is what I have tried:

```
>> df = spark.read.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "test1").load()
    
>> userSchema = StructType().add("Name", StringType(), True).add("Age", IntegerType(), True)

>> df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

>> df2 = df1.select(from_json(col("value"), userSchema))

>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- jsontostructs(value): struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
```

What I want is:

```
>> df2.printSchema()
root
|-- Name: string (nullable = true)
|-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
```

Is there any way to get the desired schema?

Comment: How does your input data / json looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, here is the how I achieved this:

```
 df2 = df1.select(from_json(col("value"),userSchema)).select("jsontostructs(value).*")
```